# Sticky header after small scroll

Tags: fix-my-code, jquery

I am working on Urban Life template of joomla XTC framework. Its header can be made sticky from back-end (I made it non-sticky from back-end). I am adding a div which contains a banner above the existing header of template and it should be non sticky. while the header containing menu should stick after scroll. I added the following code

```
$(function(){


        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#header').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});

                } else {
                        $('#header').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});

                }
        });
  });
```

The existing code of template is as follows

```
<?php if ($stickyClass == 'sticky' && !$xtc->agent->isMobile) { ?>
<script>
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      if (jQuery("#headerwrap").offset().top > 1) {
          jQuery("#headerwrap").addClass("stickyscroll")
      } else {
          jQuery("#headerwrap").removeClass("stickyscroll")
      }
  });

</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Now to display we have the following code in the body. Note the div top is added by me.

```
<body class="<?php echo $pageview;?> <?php echo $stickyClass;?> <?php echo $pageclass; ?> <?php echo $extension; ?>">


    <div id="headerwrap" class="<?php echo $stickyClass;?> xtc-bodygutter">

        <div id="top">
        <p style=""><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid #ffffff; width: 725px;" src="images/banners/jeeptop.gif" alt="" /></p>
        </div>


        <div id="header" class="<?php echo $hdclass; ?> clearfix">
            <div id="logo" class="hd2">
                <a class="hideTxt" href="index.php">
                    <?php echo $app->getCfg('sitename');?>
                </a>
            </div>
```

It didn't work. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: "It didn't work" means what? Is the javascript not getting called? Is the css set on the wrong element? Not sure that anyone can pick up this and actually provide a solid answer.

Comment: this will work better way. http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/jquery-simple-sticky-header-on-scroll/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, disable the sticky header for your template. The add the following into your CSS file:

```
#header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then your jQuery scroll detection will be as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var headerwrap = $('#header');

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var topDist = 100;

        if( scroll > topDist ) {
            headerwrap.addClass('sticky');
        }
        else {
            headerwrap.removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });

});
```

You can of course change `100` which is the scroll offset to whatever you wish. Just remember that adding a class to an element and targeting that class via CSS is far better than actually using jQuery to add CSS to an element.

Hope this helps

Comment: It also didn't work. Actually I have tested my code in html file and it was working perfectly but not working in the template.

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, I just added #header.sticky in CSS file instead of .sticky and it worked.